# Is GCC's -march parameter a synonym for multiple different parameters?

Tags: gcc

Is GCC's -march parameter a synonym for multiple different parameters?
For example, let's take `-march=core2`, is it a synonym for:

```
-mtune=core2
-mmmx
-msse
-msse2
-msse3
-mssse3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking through `gcc/config/i386/i386.c`'s `ix86_option_override_internal()`, it would be yes for all types of `-march` (at least for x86).

Explaining why would take quite a while and I'm very bad at long explanations so you'll have to look through that function yourself if you want to know why.